# $wpdb class and whether or not a prepared statement is actually needed in the following php code example

Tags: php, wordpress, class, prepared-statement

Been reading up a lot on prepared statements, and one thing I read, was that if your using the global $wpdb class, is that you shouldn't need to pre-sanitize.

The following bit of code below uses the $wpdb class, and would like to know, whether the following code would be safe as it is, or whether a prepared statement, should be introduced???

```
$products = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `cart`.`prodid`,
 `cart`.`name`
 FROM `" . WPSC_TABLE_CART_CONTENTS . "` AS `cart`
 INNER JOIN `" . WPSC_TABLE_PURCHASE_LOGS . "` AS `logs`
 ON `cart`.`purchaseid` = `logs`.`id`
 WHERE `logs`.`processed` >= 2
 AND `logs`.`date` >= " . $months[0] . "
 GROUP BY `cart`.`prodid`
 ORDER BY SUM(`cart`.`price` * `cart`.`quantity`) DESC
 LIMIT 4", ARRAY_A ); //get 4 products with top income in 4 last months.
```

Should the above code be changed to the following?

```
 $products = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT `cart`.`prodid`,
 `cart`.`name`
 FROM `%s` AS `cart`
 INNER JOIN `%s` AS `logs`
 ON `cart`.`purchaseid` = `logs`.`id`
 WHERE `logs`.`processed` >= 2
 AND `logs`.`date` >= %s
 GROUP BY `cart`.`prodid`
 ORDER BY SUM(`cart`.`price` * `cart`.`quantity`) DESC
 LIMIT 4", WPSC_TABLE_CART_CONTENTS, WPSC_TABLE_PURCHASE_LOGS, $months[0]), ARRAY_A )); //get 4 products with top income in 4 last months.
```

Read up on the wpdb class, and introduced a prepared statement.

Comment: Personally I use it as a best practice because it ensures that I don't accidentally leave a vulnerable user based input somewhere.  Same goes for sanitizing all of the inputs before using them.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Makes sense, better to have it in place, than not to have it place. Does my code look correct with the prepared statement incorporated? New to php, so not sure if my code is 100% correct

Comment: It does look correct. I tend to format a bit different.  Normally I set up the prepared query first, then reference it separately in the `get_results` query.  So I've never done it the way you have here, so can't answer fully.
If this fails, try splitting it like this: `$products_prep = $wpdb->prepare()` and then `$products = $wpdb->get_results()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do that only for user input queries to avoid any code injection.

For example, if `$months[0]` is coming from some user input parameter, sure, use the `prepare` statement, but all your current variables appear to be hard coded, there's no need for it.